# How to make my piece go up to the next row in snakes and ladders c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
namespace SnakeNLadder
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        const int START_ROW = 11;
        int _diceRoll;
        int _currPlayer;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _currPlayer = 1;
        }



        private void btnDiceRoll_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // generate a random number right here
            _diceRoll = 4;
            //Update label here
            lblDiceRoll.Text = _diceRoll.ToString();
            //move the piece by resetting the row and column values
            MovePiece();
        }



        private void MovePiece()
        {
            // first thing to do who to move
            // bvP1 - string name. #
            string playerName = "bvP" + _currPlayer.ToString();
            BoxView curr = (BoxView)GrdBoard.FindByName(playerName);
            int currCol = (int)curr.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

            // First move
            if (START_ROW == (int)curr.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty))
            {
                curr.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, START_ROW - 1);
                _diceRoll--;
            }

            //else
            //{
            //  currCol++;
            //}

                curr.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, currCol + _diceRoll);
            


        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Im having trouble with the pieces moving it only moves by four not randomly and when it does move it only goes straight it wont move itself upwards to the next column

Comment: `_diceRoll = 4;`  [4 is not a random number](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: to move an item on a Grid, you need to remove it from the Grid's Children and then re-insert it at the new row/col